# SurfaceView blinking when i try to hide it

Tags: android, surfaceview

I use `SurfaceView` to draw coordinate grid and outlines for future custom views. When I done with drawing outlines, I hide `SurfaceView` (`mySurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`) and screen splashes black on this moment. How to resolve this problem?
[Sample project](https://github.com/gvozditskiy/SurfaceBlinking)

**MySurfaceView**

```
    public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    float[] gridLines;
    Canvas canvas;
    PointF oldPos = new PointF();
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    final int mStep = 15;
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        PointF newPos = new PointF();
        float top;
        float left;
        float bottom;
        float right;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                oldPos.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                drawGrid(canvas);
                newPos.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                top = Math.min(oldPos.y, newPos.y);
                left = Math.min(oldPos.x, newPos.x);
                bottom = Math.max(oldPos.y, newPos.y);
                right = Math.max(oldPos.x, newPos.x);
                int l = (int) left / mStep;
                l *= mStep;
                int r = (int) right / mStep;
                r *= mStep;
                int t = (int) top / mStep;
                t *= mStep;
                int b = (int) bottom / mStep;
                b *= mStep;
                paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
                canvas.drawRect(l, t, r, b, paint);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void drawGrid(Canvas canvas) {
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawLines(gridLines, paint);
    }

    private float[] getLines(int step) {
        final List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<>();
        int right = this.getRight();
        int bottom = this.getBottom();
        for (int x = 0; x < right; x += step) {
                floatList.add((float) x);
                floatList.add(0f);
                floatList.add((float) x);
                floatList.add((float) bottom);

        }
        for (int y = 0; y < bottom; y += step) {
                floatList.add(0f);
                floatList.add((float) y);
                floatList.add((float) right);
                floatList.add((float) y);
        }

        float[] rez = new float[floatList.size()];
        for (int k = 0; k < floatList.size(); k++) {
            rez[k] = floatList.get(k);
        }
        return rez;
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        holder = surfaceHolder;
        gridLines = getLines(mStep);
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        drawGrid(canvas);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        drawGrid(canvas);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }
}
```

**MainFragment**

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;


    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mySurfaceView = (MySurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        mySurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_fragment_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.vis:
                if (mySurfaceView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                    item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_show));
                    mySurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_hide));
                    mySurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gvozditskiy.surfaceblinking.MainFragment">

    <com.gvozditskiy.surfaceblinking.MySurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```